# String not recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: c#

I just want to get the number of days from the `FromDate` to the `ToDate`:

```
string dt_now = DateTime.Now.ToString("m/d/yyyy");
num_days = (Convert.ToDateTime(dt_now) - Convert.ToDateTime(dr4.GetString(13))).Days;
```

`dr4.GetString(13)` is from the database with the same format as **m/d/yyyy**

Sample data for `dr4.GetString(13)`:

- 3/20/2018
- 1/19/2013
- 2/28/2013
- 3/19/2014
- 2/22/2017
- 10/6/2017

But I am getting an error:

> String not recognized as a valid DateTime

How should I properly do it?

Comment: Can you post the ```dr4.GetString(13)``` result separately please?

Comment: I see two problems here: 1) You're converting a datetime (`DateTime.Now`) to a string, only to immediately convert it back to a `DateTime` - why not use `DateTime.Now` in place of `Convert.ToDateTime(dt_now)`? 2) Why is the date in your `DataRow` a string? Can you not store it as a `DateTime`? --- And, as Michael asks, please provide the value of `dr4.GetString(13)`.

Comment: Rather than using `Convert.ToDateTime()`, use `DateTime.ParseExact()` for specified format. But it's better to store the date values as datetime in your database and use `dr4.GetDateTime(13)` afterwards.

Comment: Use the answer in the linked duplicate, but change the format from `dd/MM/yyyy` to `M/d/yyyy`

Comment: I understand and thank you for the suggestion about changing the format in the database, but if I do that, should I also change the code of save/update? If it is, then I think it would be somehow tedious. =(

Comment: @MDB Unfortunately doing things the correct way is often tedious, but it helps you in the long run because you don't need to do a lot of conversions between strings and dates. It also reduces the potential for mistakes (assuming the format is M/d/yyyy when it's really d/M/yyyy, for example)

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks @John. I will try to use the proper format in the database and will get back on this once I got no error. =)

Comment: Should I use Date or DateTime format in the database? I only need the 1/1/2018 format. not the time. If yes, then how to get it? dr4.GetDate(13)?

Comment: `Date` should be fine. In C#, there is no `Date` object, so you will still use it as `DateTime` - just with a 0 time component (the same as doing `DateTime.Now.Date`).

Comment: @MDB As I said before, you can use `GetDateTime` for `datetime` column -  just omit the time part (there is no `GetDate` for `DataReader`).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using string to represent date formats, better to store date values as `datetime` data type in your database and use [`DataReader.GetDateTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) to retrieve it:

```
// common usage
num_days = (DateTime.Now - dr4.GetDateTime(13)).Days;

// alternative with Subtract()
num_days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dr4.GetDateTime(13)).Days;
```

For current state, use this code:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dr4.GetString(13).Trim(), "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
num_days = DateTime.Now.Subtract(date).Days;
```

Comment: WIth your code for the current state, I still get the same error.

Comment: Try capture the string data, is it represented as proper date format? You should also check for possible leading/trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply do this:

```
var provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var format = "M/d/yyyy";
var d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);

Console.WriteLine("   Days:         {0,3}", (DateTime.Now - d2).Days);
```

Reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totaldays?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Timespan` class like this:

```
string dr4 = "10/2/2018";

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(dr4, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal));

int result = duration.Days;
```